# How to call an hardhat plugin in a hardhat task?

Tags: javascript, hardhat

I'm trying to create an hardhat task calling an hardhat extension, i'm using nodejs spawn but It doesn't work :/

How can I get this working ?

./tasks/checkk.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process')

task("checkk", "check contract's code on etherscan")
    .addPositionalParam("myContract")
    .setAction(async (taskArgs, hre) => {
        const argsFile = `../args/${taskArgs.myContract}.js`

        // after this line this is pseudo code only, nothing works...
        const address = fs.readFile(`./addresses/${taskArgs.myContract}_${hre.network.name}_ADDRESS.txt`, 'utf-8')

        const myCommand = `npx hardhat verify --network ${hre.network.name} ${address} --constructor-args ${argsFile}`
        const command = spawn('myCommand', {
            stdio: 'inherit',
            shell: true
        })
        command.stdout.on('data', (output) => {
            console.log("Output: ", output.toString())
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, hre.run is what I needed.

```
const fs = require('fs');

task("checkk", "check contract's code on etherscan : checkk MyContract --network MyNetwork")
    .addPositionalParam("myContract")
    .setAction(async (taskArgs, hre) => {
        const CONTRACT_ARGUMENTS = require(`../args/${taskArgs.myContract}.js`)
        const address = fs.readFileSync(`./addresses/${taskArgs.myContract}_${hre.network.name}_ADDRESS.txt`, "utf8")

        await hre.run("verify:verify", {
            address: address,
            constructorArguments: CONTRACT_ARGUMENTS,
        });

    })
```